Cannot debug into referenced project in Visual Studio
I am trying to debug my application using the System.ServiceModel.Primitives library. I need to break into the ServiceModel in order to debug the data that is transferred. I Downloaded the code of the library from HERE. In the attached image you can see a method from the library that is called from inside my application, but i have the following issues:

I cannot use the visual Studio breakpoint. The one in the image in line 128 was not hit
I can break only by using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); as in line 137
hovering over the method's arguments does not show its contents, but {...} instead so i cannot debug.
the information above line 126 says 0 references which is obviously false as i am inside the method from somewhere


I have already done the following:

Both projects are in Debug
"Enable just my code" is unchecked
"Suppress JIT optimizations" is checked
in the modules window symbols show as loaded and are up to date.
I am using .NET 8.0.0 and visual studio 2022-17.11.0
The calling application is an android Xamarin

Can you please help me understand the issue?

You haven't mentioned "Automatically suppress JIT optimizations for debugged methods (.NET 8+ only)" - is that also selected?

Yes, thank you, that is selected too.

Could you check if the referenced project(ServiceModel.dll) is loaded while debugging from Debug->Windows->Modules? Besides, it's better if you can share a Minimalsample to help reproduce.

Are you following this guide to debug DLLs?
